Solana TransactionExpiredTimeoutError : Transaction was not confirmed in 30.00 seconds
We purchased the Paid RPC in Quicknode.
Plan - Solana Digital Asset Standard API by QuickNode
Please respond quickly. And more customers are using our NFT platform.
Please let me know what actions are being taken.
Issue :
NftMintingDetailsComponent ~ this.dataService.postRequest ~  this.error: TransactionExpiredTimeoutError: Transaction was not confirmed in 30.00 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or failed. Check signature 2fj22B2a1RTixEwQhaB5rMKpAR2biEv5Hqa45RA5szUbJv8kzmHtxkmwjL3pmoXP2dDmEJ8TPC9vzGZY4EGgQjgb using the Solana Explorer or CLI tools.
at main.cfecd82b7705d8ca.js:1:404986
at Generator.next ()
at l (main.cfecd82b7705d8ca.js:1:1141129)
at X (main.cfecd82b7705d8ca.js:1:1141340)
at v.invoke (polyfills.25996055e980a3f2.js:1:6569)
at Object.onInvoke (main.cfecd82b7705d8ca.js:1:912876)
at v.invoke (polyfills.25996055e980a3f2.js:1:6509)
at L.run (polyfills.25996055e980a3f2.js:1:1950)
at polyfills.25996055e980a3f2.js:1:16779
at v.invokeTask (polyfills.25996055e980a3f2.js:1:7187)

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

From the question, I assume you're confirming transactions with connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "confirmed)
Try using this instead:
const block = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");
const result = await connection.confirmTransaction(
    {
      signature,
      ...block,
    },
    "confirmed",
);

const error = result.value.err;
if (error) {
    throw Error(error.toString());
}

This will confirm based on block height rather than a 30sec threshold. Additionally, if you aren't already, consider prepending a priority fee to your transactions:
const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: <microlamport fee>,
});

EDIT: There are better ways to do confirmations that are a bit more involved, but those are out of the scope of this question
